# Test performance of HTTPS installed by TOMCAT

Tags: tomcat, https, openssl

all.

Recently, we want to build some HTTPS service on Linux platform for providing some security content.

**Firstly**, we found the guide Apache Tomcat 7 (7.0.42) - SSL Configuration HOW-TO.htm in TOMCAT official website, and there are two solutions to install HTTPS service. (http://www.cjsdn.net/Doc/Tomcat7/ssl-howto.html)

(1) JSSE: Use keytool in JDK to generate keystore and certificate. Insert the following codes into file **server.xml** in folder CONF of TOMCAT. The protocol implemented is 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol'.

```
< Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="800" clientAuth="false"
disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="400"
port="8443" keystoreFile="/home/jsse/sslserverkeys" keystorePass="123456"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Start TOMCAT service, all the procedures are OK. People can open "https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/SSLpages/Resource_mp.xml" by using broswer.

(2) APR: Install OPENSSL, install APR package, install TOMDAT-NATIVE, and then insert the following codes into server.xml. The protocol implemented is 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol'. Generate the following KEY & certificate by OPENSSL command.

CA - KEY & certificate

1. openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 1024
2. openssl req -new -out ca-req.csr -key ca-key.pem
3. openssl x509 -req -in ca-req.csr -out ca-cert.pem -signkey ca-key.pem -days 3650
4. openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in ca-cert.pem -inkey ca-key.pem -out ca.p12

Server - KEY & certificate

1. openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
2. openssl req -new -out server-req.csr -key server-key.pem  (10.180.26.156)
3. openssl x509 -req -in server-req.csr -out server-cert.pem -signkey server-key.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -days 3650
4. openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in server-cert.pem -inkey server-key.pem -out server.p12

> < Connector **protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"**
>   SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="800"  maxThreads="400"
>   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" port="8443"
>   SSLProtocol="TLSv1" SSLCipherSuite="ALL" scheme="https" secure="true"
>   **SSLCertificateFile="/home/apr/ssl/server-cert.pem"**
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile="/home/apr/ssl/server-key.pem"
>   **SSLCACertificateFile="/home/apr/ssl/ca-cert.pem"** SSLCACertificatePath="/home/apr/ssl" SSLPassword="123456"  />

Start TOMCAT service, all the procedures are OK (including OPENSSL component). People can open "https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/SSLpages/Resource_mp.xml" by using broswer.

**Secondly**, when the HTTPS has been installed, the procedure of performance test must be started.

We found many tools about testing 'concurrency of visiting page', at last, 'Siege' is great and easy to use. And it just runs on Linux just like:

**siege -c 500 -r 50 -u "https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/SSLpages/Resource_mp.xml"**

(1) TOMCAT - JSSE model
After running the above command on Linux, the correct result list can be achieved.

Transactions:                  25000

hitsAvailability:              100.00 %

secsTransaction rate:          677.51

trans/secThroughput:           2.36 MB/sec

Concurrency:                   16.90

Successful transactions:       25000

Failed transactions:               0

(2) TOMCAT - APR model

**siege -c 50 -r 10 -u "https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8443/SSLpages/Resource_mp.xml"**

After running the above command on Linux, the correct result list **can not be achieved**.

Successful transactions:       0

Failed transactions:           500

WHY ? and the siege tool has not written any ERROR message into LOG.

Should I insert the CA certificate into OPENSSL default folder ?

Should I generate the trust file about trusting CA certificate and put it into somewhere ?

But in JSSE model, I only generate the keystore by JDK which can be imported by tomcat. Siege can work successfully.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated !!!

Comment: You will need to provide some more information. For example, what happens when you try to load `https://...../Resource_mp.xml` in a browser? Do you get a response? What is it?

Comment: Thank you for your response! There are two cases. One: the CA certificate (.P12) is not installed into browser(IE), people who open "https://...../Resource_mp.xml" in browser will get some warning for processing. The other: install CA certificate (.P12) into browser(IE), then people can visit the XML without any warning, which means: IE trust CA certificate (made by myself), the CA trust server certificate ( run the above command 'openssl x509 -req -in server-req.csr -out server-cert.pem -signkey server-key.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -days 3650' ).

Comment: I meant: what happens when you visit the site when in JSSE (BIO or NIO) mode versus OpenSSL mode (APR)?

Comment: They are showing the same response. Tomcat with JSSE or APR can be started successfully, and when people visit the site, they always get the warning for progressing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your certificate and/or CA certificate file don't have a CA certificate (or chain certificate) required for the client to establish a chain-of-trust between your server and a recognized CA.

Do you need any intermediate certificates for your CA? Have you installed them in your `SSLCACertificateFile` or `SSLCACertificatePath`? I'm not sure what Tomcat does if you specify both, BTW.